# Prestashop 1.7.8.8 API - Problem with a adding an order to the store from BL

Tags: api, external

Everything was working fine for 4 months before.

I had automatic minor updates turned on, so it did auto update from `1.7.8.8` to `1.7.8.9`

A problem has arisen, concerning the synchronization of stock levels from Baselinker Marketplace (Allegro) to the store (Presta).

I went back from a copy to `1.7.8.8` but that didn't help either.

I have enabled debug mode in Prestashop.

On an example order whose status was not syncing, I manually selected "Resubmit order to store".

The BL log indicated:

```
Error adding the order to the store: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function validateOrder() on bool in 
/home/pawelj/domains/mydomena/public_html/classes/order/Order.php:1727 Stack trace: #0 
/home/pawelj/domains/mydomena/public_html/classes/webservice/WebserviceRequest.php(1632): OrderCore->addWs() #1 
/home/pawelj/domains/mydomena/public_html/classes/webservice/WebserviceRequest.php(1418): WebserviceRequestCore->saveEntityFromXml(201) #2 
/home/pawelj/domains/mydomena/public_html/classes/webservice/WebserviceRequest.php(567): WebserviceRequestCore->executeEntityPost() #3 
/home/pawelj/domains/mydomena/public_html/webservice/dispatcher.php(90): WebserviceRequestCore->fetch('TKI19PQK94EBM6W...', 'POST', 'orders', Array, false, '<?xml version="...') #4 {main} thrown in /home/pawelj/domains/mydomena/public_html/classes/order/Order.php on line 1727
```

How to fix it?

I have been enabling and disabling mod_security for the domain
I rolled back to version 1.7.8.8
In the BL integration, in the "Orders" section, I have the option of transferring orders to the store enabled